# Selenium C# GetLog returns NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have dusted off some old code with I know used to work but no longer appears to function.
Namely

```
var browserLogs = Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
```

This used to return any console log entries but now I get the following
[image]

I last used this code about 2 years ago so my questions are:

> What has changed in Chrome? What do I need to change on my code to get
> this working again?

I am using Chrome 85.x etc with matching ChromeDriver, C# and Selenium. Driver is correctly initialised and a valid web page has rendered. Also I have this as in my driver options

```
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
```

Any ideas folks?

More code below

```
        public static void BeforeFeature(int server, string title)
    {
        if (server == 1) ResetReportVariables(TestUrls.DomainLive, title);
        if (server == 2) ResetReportVariables(TestUrls.Domain, title);
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("disable-browser-side-navigation");
        options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.AddArgument("ignore-ssl-errors");
        options.AddArgument("disable-popup-blocking");
        options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
        options.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
        options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
        Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TestValues.DelayShort);
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TestValues.DelayShort);
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TestValues.DelayShort);
        Driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
    }


Scenario Outline: Validate the following pages on live site
Given that I browse to "<url>" page on "1" server
Then  no console errors were detected

Examples:
  | url             |
  | /               |


        [Given(@"that I browse to ""(.*)"" page on ""(.*)"" server")]
    public void GivenThatIBrowseToPageOnServer(string url, int server)
    {
        Visit(url, server);
    }


    [Then(@"no console errors were detected")]
    public void ThenNoConsoleErrorsWereDetected()
    {
        ValidateTheConsoleResults();
    }

        protected void Visit(string ext, int server)
    {
        WriteToReport(GetTheCurrentMethod());
        if (server == 1)
            ThisUrl = LiveUrl;
        else
            ThisUrl = PageUrl;

        WriteToReport("Load page " + ThisUrl);
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ThisUrl + ext);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.UrlContains(ThisUrl));
    }


        protected void ValidateTheConsoleResults()
    {
        WriteToReport(GetTheCurrentMethod());
        Visit();
        var errors = 0;
        //now we check the logs for errors
        var browserLogs = Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
        if (browserLogs.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var log in browserLogs)
            {
                if (log.Level.Equals(LogLevel.Warning))
                {
                    WriteToReport("Logged Warning - " + log);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteToReport("Logged Error - " + log);
                    errors++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (errors != 0) AssertFalse(errors + " Console errors detected");
        else AssertTrue("No console errors detected");
    }
```

Comment: can you provide your codes here ?

Comment: Hi Justin, code added to the question

Comment: @Kev Have you tried the 4.0 alpha .NET bindings? When `chromedriver` implemented the W3C WebDriver Specification, the HTTP end point used by the bindings for logs went away. There were some changes to get it back, but they didn’t land until 4.0 alpha 1 of the .NET bindings, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @JimEvans, thanks I will look into that

Comment: @JimEvans that solved it, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JimEvans you are a star
That solved it, many thanks